# Why function assignment to field of type var fails when function has wildcard character _

Tags: scala

I found a weird scenario while playing with scala functions and wildcard character `_`

Why following Scala function assignment to a `field` of type `val` works but it fails with a `field` of type `var` ?

Following code works well without error :

```
scala> val isEven : (Int => Boolean) = _%2 == 0
isEven: Int => Boolean = $$Lambda$1522/1959940703@3b92dd48
```

But, assigning the same function to `var` fails :

```
scala> var isEven : (Int => Boolean) = _%2 == 0
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but identifier found.
       var isEven : (Int => Boolean) = _%2 == 0
```

Am I missing something here while assigning a `function` to `var` ?

Comment: I don't have same problem in [scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/q0lFTQfkSa21pdULUDOEXw).

Comment: Note that a `var` of a function rarely make sense in any case.

Comment: @Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez, Agree with your comment. var does not make any sense for function assignment. I just found this scenario while doing random practice code.

Comment: @ scastie, I also tried in scastie, it works there. Have you tried in your system where you have scala ? I am using scala 2.12.6. Can it be issue with scala version ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a bug [parser issue with var and _: default-value syntax and placeholder syntax collide #11437](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/11437) fixed starting Scala 2.13.1 by [RHS of var def is an expr #7894](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/7894)